# Adding CustomClassObjects to Dictionary as values

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a task where I need to have two values for one key in Dictionary. 
Solution found in web is to make new class with two fields and use it's objects as values.

But how can I assign value to my CustomClassObjects from Dictionary's for loop?
Here is the code:

```
Dictionary<char, Huffmans> HuffmanDictionary = new Dictionary<char, Huffmans>();
        Program.text = File.ReadAllText(Program.sourcetext);
        char character;
        for (int i = 0; i < Program.text.Length; i++)
        {
            counter++;
            character = Convert.ToChar(Program.text[i]);
            if (HuffmanDictionary.ContainsKey(character))
                HuffmanDictionary[character].probability++;
            else
                HuffmanDictionary.Add(character, 1);// here is the problem, obviously program can't assign value directly to class... 
        }
public class Huffmans
{
    public int code = 0;
    public double probability = 0;
}
```

Basically, I need to assign only "probability" values on this step. Should I call constructor for "Huffmans " on each iteration?

Big thanks for any help, Alex

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: It was saying "cannot convert from "int" to "Huffmans".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate your class before adding the value:

```
HuffmanDictionary.Add(character, 1);
```

Should be:

```
HuffmanDictionary.Add(character, new Huffmans{ code = 1 });
```

Alternatively you can create a constructor for your class:

```
public class Huffmans
{
    public Huffmans(int _code)
    {
       code = _code;
    }

    public int code = 0;
    public double probability = 0;
}
```

then you can do:

```
 HuffmanDictionary.Add(character, new Huffmans(1));
```

**EDIT:**
   Some more clarification:

```
HuffmanDictionary.Add(character, 1);
```

fails because you are passing a type `int` into the dictionary but it is expecting the type `Huffmans`. Our dictionary is : `Dictionary<char,Huffmans>()`

```
HuffmanDictionary.Add(character, new Huffmans{ code = 1 });
```

works because now we are creating a **new** object of type `Huffmans` and we are setting the `code value` to 1.

Not sure if I understood your comment correctly, but effectively we are doing the same as:

```
var newHuffmans = new Huffmans{ code = 1 };
HuffmanDictionary.Add(character, newHuffmans);
```

But rather than writing out all that code and creating a named variable with our class, we skip this and pass it directly into the dictionary.

Comment: Wow, thanks for fast answer! Gonna check it right now. Could you please explain, what exactly happens in first scenario? did we create new instance of "Huffmans"? If yes, which name will be given to this instance? Because it's not the case when we give name directly, like

Huffmans _name_ = new Huffmans

Comment: Thanks, it works. Yes, my second question was about this "unnamed variable". Will it be stored just like named one or it's temporary? If I got it right, I can call for unnamed variable only through it's corresponding key in Dictionary?